# Uploading Image to a website using HttpWebRequest in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

how i can upload any image to a website using HttpWebrequest in WP7 Mango?? and another doubt regarding with HttpWebequest is that how i can achieve the secured version of HttpWebRequest in WP7 Mango?? Does new add-on sockets in wp7 has any role in secured data transfer over HttpWebequest? please help me on this issues.. ThanX in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311403/windows-phone-7-how-to-upload-picture-to-server) for uploading to a server using HttpWebRequest.

Using sockets would be an alternative approach, but I would ignore this unless you have a specific requierment to do it this way.

Sending the image over HTTPS should be no problem as long as you have a certificate with a root cert recognised by the phone.