# C# post request using socks proxy operation time out

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, socks

I am creating an application to post an image and data in form of name value collection using socks proxy. For socks proxy i am using Org.Mantalis.dll and SocksWebProxy.dll . 
On sending request it gives error `Operation Timed Out`.

```
public static void HttpUploadFile(string url, string file, string paramName, string contentType, NameValueCollection nvc)
    {
        IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9151);
        Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        server.Connect(endPoint);
        server.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("AUTHENTICATE \"" + authPwd + "\"" + Environment.NewLine));
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        int receivedDataLength = server.Receive(data);
        //get a new identity
        server.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("SIGNAL NEWNYM" + Environment.NewLine));
        data = new byte[1024];
        receivedDataLength = server.Receive(data);
        string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, receivedDataLength);

        if (!stringData.Contains("250"))
        {
            server.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            server.Close();
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Process Begins ... ");
        string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
        byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");
        byte[] boundarybytesF = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("--" + boundary + "\r\n");  // the first time it itereates, you need to make sure it doesn't put too many new paragraphs down or it completely messes up poor webbrick.  

        com.LandonKey.SocksWebProxy.Proxy.ProxyConfig config = new com.LandonKey.SocksWebProxy.Proxy.ProxyConfig(IPAddress.Loopback, 8181, IPAddress.Loopback, 9150, com.LandonKey.SocksWebProxy.Proxy.ProxyConfig.SocksVersion.Five);
        HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        wr.Proxy = new SocksWebProxy(config);
        wr.Method = "POST";
        wr.KeepAlive = true;
        wr.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        wr.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        var nvc2 = new NameValueCollection();
        nvc2.Add("Accepts-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5");
        wr.Headers.Add(nvc2);
        wr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;


        Stream rs = wr.GetRequestStream();

        bool firstLoop = true;
        string formdataTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n{1}";
        foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)
        {
            if (firstLoop)
            {
                rs.Write(boundarybytesF, 0, boundarybytesF.Length);
                firstLoop = false;
            }
            else
            {
                rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
            }
            string formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, key, nvc[key]);
            byte[] formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);
            rs.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);
        }
        rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);

        string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n";
        string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, paramName, new FileInfo(file).Name, contentType);
        byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
        rs.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);

        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            rs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        fileStream.Close();

        byte[] trailer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
        rs.Write(trailer, 0, trailer.Length);
        rs.Close();

        WebResponse wresp = null;
        try
        {
            wresp = wr.GetResponse();
            Stream stream2 = wresp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (wresp != null)
            {
                wresp.Close();
                wresp = null;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            wr = null;

            server.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            server.Close();
        }
    }
```

I have tried many approaches from stackoverflow and other blogs but it always gives the same error of "Operation timed out".

Also i have tried `GET` request from this approach and it works perfectly.

Comment: *"I have tried many approaches from stackoverflow and other blogs"*; which ones?

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043997/uploading-an-image-using-c-sharp-and-webrequest and these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954287/how-to-upload-file-to-server-with-http-post-multipart-form-data